# How do I delete a large amount of photos from iPhoto that were taken on the same device (not sequential)

Tags: photos, photos.app

I uploaded a ton of photos from a friend's iPhone before wiping her phone and transferring the photos to a flash drive for her to keep (I use the iPhone for myself now).  But now all of her photos are interspersed throughout my photos on iPhoto and it is very bothersome.  I need to delete all her photos from iPhoto without individually selecting them.  Is there a function I can use to select all photos taken on a certain device before a certain time period or something?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to do an advanced search using Spotlight and configure the search parameters accordingly. Spotlight supports device make and model as well as creation date.

[image: Spotlight search]

Comment: Okay this might be of some use: I still have the folder of ALL the photos I want to delete.....could I somehow use this folder to take out the same photos out of my iPhoto library?